# Redmine "Unable to connect to svn repository"

Tags: linux, svn, redmine

I have installed a Redmine 3 and a Subversion 1.7 in the same server (contos7), but when I click the tab of repository,I got a 404 error.

[404 The entry or revision was not found in repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WmsZv.png)

I got the error message as below:

```
App 2716 stderr: svn: E000013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn://192.168.1.110/test'
App 2716 stderr: svn: E000013: Can't connect to host '192.168.1.110': Permission denied
App 2716 stderr: svn: E000013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn://192.168.1.110/test'
App 2716 stderr: svn: E000013: Can't connect to host '192.168.1.110': Permission denied
App 2716 stderr: svn: E000013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'svn://192.168.1.110/test'
App 2716 stderr: svn: E000013: Can't connect to host '192.168.1.110': Permission denied
App 2716 stderr: Error parsing svn output: No close tag for /lists/list
App 2716 stderr: Line: 4
App 2716 stderr: Position: 89
App 2716 stderr: Last 80 unconsumed characters:
App 2716 stderr: 
App 2716 stderr: Output was:
App 2716 stderr:  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
App 2716 stderr: <lists>
App 2716 stderr: <list
App 2716 stderr:    path="svn://192.168.1.110/test">
App 2716 stderr: 
App 2716 stderr:   Rendered common/error.html.erb within layouts/base (5.3ms)
App 2716 stderr: Completed 404 Not Found in 1444ms (Views: 234.4ms | ActiveRecord: 107.1ms)
```

I searched for a lot of solutions, but they do not solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using an `http://server.domain/svn/repos` link instead of an SVN link. 
First, use the `http://server.domain/svn/repos` link with a browser and try logging in.

If you are successful replace the URL in the Redmine repository setting and provide your guest userid and password.

Make sure that link is complete as seen in your Apache configuration for svn.

The issue for you is the Apache of your server is not allowing an SVN connection. Maybe you have not configured it for an SVN access configuration(Port `3690`).

Check in the `etc/apache2` folder. You will find your apache config files. Check whether you have provided a `http://` access or an `svn://` access. By default apache server allows `http://` access and not `svn://` access.

There is a difference in `http://` and `svn://` access. Http is over `8080` which is usually opened and configured. SVN is over `3690` which is usually not opened and needs to be configured in the apache.